# Reputation notifications not showing after my answer was deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, deleted-answers

Recently, a question that I had answered was closed and deleted (along with my answer) for being a duplicate, and I lost all the reputation (105 points) I'd gained from my answer. That's no problem, but what was strange was that afterwards I didn't get any notifications for reputation gained from upvotes or accepts on different answers until my reputation increased back to what it was before the deletion. Is this a bug? I haven't seen that happen when I've lost reputation for other reasons, such as users being deleted.

Comment: I'd suspect caching issues.

Comment: Related: [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements (MSE)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223006/184030)

Comment: what's more interesting is why was a duplicate deleted. Isn't it the policy that duplicates should not be deleted while all other closed questions ought to be deleted?

Comment: @e4c5 I suspect it was deleted because it seemed like a particularly egregious case of FGITW (a commenter said "Beat me to it by 10 seconds"). I don't dispute it because it is clearly a duplicate, although I didn't find it when I searched (I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487592/randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list) but didn't search any further and just went ahead and answered it)

Comment: We do not notify on negative rep changes, only positive ones.

Comment: @Oded have you seen the comments on the [answer](/a/339393/6388243) that I deleted? It adds a bit of context.

Comment: @Oded what are you talking about ? I do see my negative rep changes !

Comment: @AntoinePelletier - sure. After opening the inbox popup. But - if you only have negative changes, the inbox doesn't light up.

Comment: @Oded I understand, but why wasn't I seeing *positive* rep changes after the deletion?

Comment: @samgak - you should be seeing them. It is possible that a JavaScript error happened and notifications stopped (a refresh would sort that), or that websockets (which is how we deliver notification data) are blocked (talking to your ISP/Helpdesk might help).

Comment: @Oded, the notifications were gone for about a week, and returned once my rep reached the level it was before my answer was deleted. I don't see how this could be related to my ISP. I would have refreshed the page lots of times over that period. I've lost large amounts of rep before (e.g. when awarding a bounty) and this weird behaviour didn't happen - I got notifications for positive rep even when my rep amount was less than it was before I awarded the bounty.

Comment: That's... strange. Could be that the notifications don't come up so long as the reputation is in "deficit". Would need to check the implementation.

Comment: This could be resolved by simply showing negative reputation changes in the notification menu...